# JavaScript regex for specific pattern

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm want to apply a regex on a string like this `word in $ctrl.words`
Want to find if the string has `in` and one string after and one before.

I try with this regex `[a-zA-Z\\d]+\\s+in\\s+[a-zA-Z\\d]+'`, but the problem are the special characters from `$ctrl.words`, the regex always return false. 
The result what i want is true for string like this
`fruit in $ctrl.fruits`
`letter in $ctrl.alphabet`

And false for strings like 
`fruit in $ctrl.fruits anything else`
`letter in $ctrl.alphabet anithing else`

Comment: Use [`/^\S+\s+in\s+\S+$/`](https://regex101.com/r/x3c6er/1).

Comment: What do you mean if the string has `in` and "one string after and one before?" Do you mean that there needs to be characters before and after the `in` - as separate words? Does the in need to have spaces around it?

Comment: Yes i'm need separate words before and after the `in`, and need have spaces too

Comment: Why are you escaping your backslashes? `[a-zA-Z\\d]` for example matches alphabetical characters, ``\``, and `d` (redundantly)

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew works for me, could you please answer the post

Comment: @PatrickRoberts Backslashes should be doubled in RegExp constructor notation, when regex delimiters are not used.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Nothing was said about a constructor though

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you need to match a string that only consists of two non-whitespace char chunks separated with `in` enclosed with whitespaces, you may use

```
/^\S+\s+in\s+\S+$/
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/x3c6er/1)

**Details**

- `^` - start of string
- `\S+` - `+ non-whitespace chars
- `\s+in\s+` - an `in` substring enclosed with 1 or more whitespaces
- `\S+` - `+ non-whitespace chars
- `$` - end of string.

JS demo:

```js
var strs = ['fruit in $ctrl.fruits', 'letter in $ctrl.alphabet', 'fruit in $ctrl.fruits anything else', 'letter in $ctrl.alphabet anithing else' ];
var rx = /^\S+\s+in\s+\S+$/;
for (var s of strs) {
  console.log(s, "=>", rx.test(s));
}
```